# How to use $location.search('term', null) in angular to hide parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, route-provider

Hi there am kind of new to angular. I need a way to hide my URL parameters from the use. After much of searching on the internet and reading the $location documentation i have come across using "`$location.search('term', null)`" as the way to do this. However there is no practical example of where it is to be placed in the code. I have place tried placing it in the $routeProvider block of code also in my controllers, neither seem to work. Can someone PLEASE help me out on this.

Thank you

Comment: should work fine in controller if terms match. Sounds like strange issue though to need to hide them. What is the higher level issue that they need to be hidden? This sounds like a design flaw

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need to avoid the user from being able to change the parameters by directly typing them in address. That's why i need them hidden.

Comment: The parameters am trying to remove are the ones trailing in the url for example in "home.html#/sacco/1/0" i need the trailing "/1/0" removed from the url after they have been used

Comment: Well that isn't part of `search` and changing them will conflict with your router. Sounds more like you need to be able to validate user access to particular values in url. Idea you are working with is not going to secure your app

Comment: Thank you. let me look for another way to secure it.